# Preventing accumulating whitespace from using "\left."

Tags: math-mode, spacing, white-space

Sorry if this has been asked before, but googling seems to not work well with "\left." or variations.

I'm using the following pattern taken from a formula on Wikipedia's Cartesian product section on infinite products, where the vertical bars match the bracket height unlike `\mid`

```
\prod_{i \in I} X_i = \left\{\left. f : I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i\ \right|\ (\forall i)(f(i) \in X_i)\right\}
```

Rendered as:

[image]

But it seems to have a small whitespace before the first word that accumulates with repeated use.

```
\begin{align*}
& \left(a\right) \\
& \left(\left.a \ \right|\ b\right) \\
& \left(\left.\left.a\ \right|\ b\ \right|\ c\right) \\
& \left(\left.\left.\left.a\ \right|\ b\ \right|\ c\ \right|\ d\right)
\end{align*}
```

Is rendered as:

[image]

Is there any way to achieve correct height vertical bars without the accumulating whitespace after the left bracket?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every `\left.` or `\right.` adds space in the amount of `\nulldelimiterspace`, so you can remove it by

```
\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
```

On the other hand, there are better ways to type the formula. I'd go with the last one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent
First attempt (yours):
\[
\left\{ \left.f\colon I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i\ \right|\ (\forall i)(f(i) \in X_i)\right\}
\]
Second attempt:
\[
\left\{ f\colon I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \;\middle|\; (\forall i)(f(i) \in X_i)\right\}
\]
Third attempt:
\[
\biggl\{ f\colon I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \biggm| (\forall i)(f(i) \in X_i)\biggr\}
\]
Fourth attempt:
\[
\Bigl\{ f\colon I \to \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \Bigm| (\forall i)(f(i) \in X_i)\Bigr\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AkariAkaori: You might also want to have a look at section 3.6 of the manual of the `mathtools` package.